# Does Google perform onClick actions?

Tags: google, javascript, googlebot, post

Can somebody approve to see, that Google (googlebot / crawler) performs onClick (or similar js) actions? It is [fact](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html), that Google performs POST - i'm interesting, whether somebody has realized any js action done by Google

Comment: Well, in tracking code of google analytics for example, there are onClick actions. You mean that or?

Comment: no, i don't mean analytics. i mean the crawler bot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is a article on Searchengineland:** http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

**They tested a lot of different typical JS use cases and most of them are handled fine by google.** But it is important to allow Google access to your js / css assets to render your whole site.
There are some rumors, the browser Chrome is only a side product of the crawler Google is using.

If SEO is important for your business i would not recommend you to implement any SEO critical js (like loading content via ajax) without heavy testing on your own.

Some time ago i set up a test too to find out which urls are crawled by google. But i guess Google only extracted the URL from the code and does not perform a real JS action. The article is in german, but "red" means "not crawled" and "green" means "crawled": http://www.sirpauls.com/welchen-links-folgt-google-ein-experiment/

Results for onclick:

```
<input type="button" name="the-button" value="THE BUTTON" onclick="window.location='http://www.domain.com/test/target.php?id=11'"/>
<button onclick="JavaScript:window.location='http://www.domain.com/test/target.php?id=18'">Click Me!</button>
```

= Not crawled

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://www.domain.com/test/target.php?id=12'">THE DIV</div>
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='http://www.domain.com/test/target.php?id=3';">Link</a>
```

= Crawled

Comment: Chrome and search engine page rendering are not rumors, however, Chrome came first. Chrome was initially the discovery channel for the render engine. I do believe they are two separate tracks because they have two different purposes, however, lessons are learned between the two and the development of either are more closely related than most products. It would make sense not to stove pipe these.

Comment: danke, Milo! Genau danach habe ich gesucht